# Django installation SyntaxError

Tags: python, django, syntax-error

I am trying to install Django on a server. When I run django-admin.py version, I get the following syntaxError:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 7, in <module>
    execfile(__file__)
  File "/u02/django-tools/django-trunk/django/bin/django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core import management
  File "/u02/django-tools/django-trunk/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 108
    commands = {name: 'django.core' for name in find_commands(__path__[0])}
                                  ^
```

Python 2.7.6 is installed, but I cannot import django.

I would very appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you paste the complete traceback and not only the end?

Comment: It looks like you are running it on Python 2.6 or earlier, dict comprehensions won't work in those earlier versions.

Comment: put `import sys; print(sys.version_info)` into `/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py` and then run the command again to see which python you are using.

Comment: Are you running on centos?

Comment: OT: if you'll have more projects on that server I strongly recommend you to use Virtualenv.

Comment: **`(O_O)"`** Python 2.6...